# How to pass data from vertex shader to fragment shader with shaders in between

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

(I'm REALLY new to this.)

I want to pass a `vec4` color from my vertex shader to fragment shader. Do I need to pass it from `vertex -> tesselation -> geometry -> fragment` or is it possible just from `vertex -> fragment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to the first, you need to pass it all the way through all the shader stages you bind to your program.